# How can I clone a GroupOfNames Active Directory Object?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, active-directory-group

I'm writing a script to take one `GroupOfNames` object and create a second group with the first groups members.  It seems like it would be a very simple piece of code:

```
$obj = Get-ADObject -Server "$server" -SearchBase $SearchBase -Filter "name -eq '$GroupName'" -Properties Member
New-ADObject -Server "$server" -Path $SearchBase -Type 'GroupOfNames' -name "$NewGroupName" -OtherAttributes @{'Member'= ($($obj.Member))}
```

When I run this the $obj gets created and I can display both the `GroupOfNames` information, as well as the list of members.  But when it calls the `New-ADObject` cmdlet, I get the following error:

```
New-ADObject : Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it is currently down, or it does not have the Active Directory Web Services running.
```

I've tried multiple variations of the code and all fail with similar errors.

Interestingly, if I loop through the list of members and add them to the group one at a time, it works, but it just takes way too long (an hour+ vs seconds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, I found that I could reliably add about 6000 members at a time. Here's the basic flow:

```
(Get-ADObject -Server "$server" -SearchBase $SearchBase -Filter { name -eq "$GroupName" } -Properties Member).Member | %{
    $SubList += [string] $_
    if($SubList.count -ge 6000) {
        Set-ADObject -Server "$server" -Identity $NewGroup -Add @{'Member'= ($SubList)}
        $SubList = @()
    }
}
if($SubList.count -gt 0) {
    Set-ADObject -Server "$server" -Identity $NewGroup -Add @{'Member'= ($SubList)}
}
```

Thank you @Raf for the push in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it casts the results of your first query, `ADPropertyValueCollection`, to a string array(untested!):

```powershell
$obj = Get-ADObject -Server "$server" -SearchBase $SearchBase 
    -Filter "name -eq '$GroupName'" -Properties Member
$m = [string[]]$obj.Member
New-ADObject -Server "$server" -Path $SearchBase -Type 'GroupOfNames' 
    -name "$NewGroupName" -OtherAttributes @{'Member'= $m}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. No change.  I get the same error. I've tried other combinations of this as well, like $m = $member | %{"'$($_)'"), thinking that maybe the string needed to be quoted.  Every combination has failed so far.

Comment: The error is clearly a red herring. Try running `$error[0] | fl * -Force` right after the error, it might shed more light on the situation.

Comment: I think you are right.  Taking your code from above, I get a large amount of error information.  I think the most telling thing may be `This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:02:00'`  I then did some additional research to discover a hard two minute timeout using the AD Module.  Looks like I may have to retool using ADO or some other method.  Suggestions?